# Display text when hovering over a rating and have stay when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to replace the `<div class="rate">Rate this product</div>` with one of the rating descriptions of `Bad, Better, Best` and so on when the user hovers over the rating and have the rating description stay when the user clicks on the rating. I'm fairly new to Jquery so I do not know where to begin.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li id="rate-1">
            <label for="rating-1"><input type="radio" value="1" name="rating" id="rating-1" />1 star</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-2">
            <label for="rating-2"><input type="radio" value="2" name="rating" id="rating-2" />2 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-3">
            <label for="rating-3"><input type="radio" value="3" name="rating" id="rating-3" />3 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-4">
            <label for="rating-4"><input type="radio" value="4" name="rating" id="rating-4" />4 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-5">
            <label for="rating-5"><input type="radio" value="5" name="rating" id="rating-5" />5 stars</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rate">Rate this product</div>
</form>
```

Descriptions

```
<div>Bad</div>
<div>Better</div>
<div>Best</div>
<div>Great</div>
<div>Good</div>
```

Comment: Well, atleast provide what you tried to implement? This is not the place that some one will code for you

Comment: You need to add CSS, and your attempts to solve this. Then someone might help you.

Comment: @Harsh Makani I was not looking for someone to code it for me I was just looking for some help

Comment: Try the css from here to get you started: https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out for jQuery (with fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cwymmznw/):

```
// HTML
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li id="rate-1">
            <label for="rating-1"><input type="radio" data-desc="Bad" value="1" name="rating" id="rating-1" />1 star</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-2">
            <label for="rating-2"><input type="radio" data-desc="Good" value="2" name="rating" id="rating-2" />2 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-3">
            <label for="rating-3"><input type="radio" data-desc="Great" value="3" name="rating" id="rating-3" />3 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-4">
            <label for="rating-4"><input type="radio" data-desc="Better" value="4" name="rating" id="rating-4" />4 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-5">
            <label for="rating-5"><input type="radio" data-desc="Best" value="5" name="rating" id="rating-5" />5 stars</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rate">Rate this product</div>
</form>

// JS
$('input').hover(function(e) {
    $('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
}, function(e) {
  if ($('.selected')) {
    $('.rate').text($('.selected').attr('data-desc'));
  } else {
    $('.rate').text('Rate this product');
  }
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
  $('.rate').text($(this).attr('data-desc'));
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li id="rate-1">
            <label for="rating-1"><input type="radio" value="1" class="rating" name="rating" id="rating-1" />1 star</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-2">
            <label for="rating-2"><input type="radio" value="2" class="rating" name="rating" id="rating-2" />2 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-3">
            <label for="rating-3"><input type="radio" value="3" class="rating" name="rating" id="rating-3" />3 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-4">
            <label for="rating-4"><input type="radio" value="4" class="rating" name="rating" id="rating-4" />4 stars</label>
        </li>
        <li id="rate-5">
            <label for="rating-5"><input type="radio" value="5" class="rating" name="rating" id="rating-5" />5 stars</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="rate">Rate this product</div>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    var rate = $( this ).find('.rating').val();

    if(rate ==1){
      $('.rate').html('bad');
    }
    if(rate == 2){
        $('.rate').html('good');
    }
    if(rate == 3){
        $('.rate').html('better');
    }
    if(rate == 4){
        $('.rate').html('best');
    }
     if(rate == 5){
        $('.rate').html('very best');
    }
  }, function() {
    var str = "Rate this product";
    $('.rate').html(str);
  }
);
</script>
```

js fiddle:- [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6ue0on6d/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read about [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) ?

```
$( "#yourSelector ).hover(
  function() {
      // show or hide here.
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement is not clear enough, you might  need something similar to this -
html

```
 <div class="bad">Bad</div>
 <div class="rate" id="rating">Rate this product</div>
```

In Jquery part -

```
$("#rating").removeClass("rate");
$("#rating").addClass("bad");
```